# Rust Error -- `internal::Local` uninitialized, which is invalid

Tags: multithreading, rust, channel

I am trying to pass enum type data to a thread using channels in Rust, but I keep getting the following error when I run the program (it compiles fine),

> thread 'thread 'main' panicked at '' panicked at 'attempted to leave type `internal::Local` uninitialized, which is invalid. Attempted to leave type `internal::Local` uninitialized, which is invalid'

Here is the code snippet,

```
use std::thread;
use crossbeam_channel::unbounded;

enum Message {
    Sum(i64, i64),
    Quit
}

fn main() {

    let (sender, receiver) = unbounded();
    
    let worker = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            match receiver.recv() {
                Some(msg) => match msg  {
                    Message::Sum(a, b) => println!("{} + {} = {}", a, b, a+b),
                    Message::Quit => {
                         println!("Thread Terminating");
                         break
                    },
                },
                None => {
                    print!("Didn't receive or unable to read the message");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    );

    sender.send(Message::Sum(10, 21));
    sender.send(Message::Quit);

    worker.join();
}
```

And here's the relevant part of `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
crossbeam-channel = "0.2.5"
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile in playground - type mismatch. What versions of dependencies do you use?

Comment: @Cerberus crossbeam-channel = "0.2.5"

Comment: in vscode, it does compile...

Comment: @MuzahirHussain That is not possible because the code is wrong. I have edited your code so that it compiles.  Please feel free to change to what you are actually using if that is somehow not representative of your problem.

Comment: I wonder if you are using a very old version of `crossbeam_channel`, from before `MaybeUninit` was added. Try updating your dependencies.

Comment: 0.2.5 is very old indeed - playground currently has 0.5.2, which has different API (and therefore the original code didn't compile). I'll check with the old version a little later.

Comment: Rolled the code back - for that version of dependency it was correct, and the dependency version is important for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: this error shows the unsoundness in an old `crossbeam` version, you must update it for your code to work.

---

If we run the code from OP with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1`, we'll see the following:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'attempted to leave type `internal::Local` uninitialized, which is invalid', /home/cerberus/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/crossbeam-epoch-0.6.1/src/internal.rs:485:59
// ...skipped
   3: core::mem::uninitialized
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/mem/mod.rs:676:9
   4: <crossbeam_epoch::internal::Local as crossbeam_epoch::sync::list::IsElement<crossbeam_epoch::internal::Local>>::entry_of
             at /home/cerberus/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/crossbeam-epoch-0.6.1/src/internal.rs:485:59
// ...skipped
```

So, this code internally uses [`core::mem::uninitialized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/mem/fn.uninitialized.html). And here's [the exact source of panic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/intrinsics.rs.html#867-872) - intrinsic function which panics if having the uninitialized value of the passed type is UB.